# Split table of contents on "Part" page

Tags: books, parts

In the code below, there is a table of contents on the "Part" page.  However, I have a lot of chapters in Part One of the document and the contents overextends the page.  How can I split the table of contents in the "Part" page in basically two columns so that all the chapters can appear correctly on the page?

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating, ltablex, dcolumn, booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}

%======================================================================================
%   MAIN TABLE OF CONTENTS
%======================================================================================

\usepackage{titletoc} % Required for manipulating the table of contents

\contentsmargin{0cm} % Removes the default margin

% Part text styling
\titlecontents{part}[0cm]
{\addvspace{20pt}\centering\large\bfseries}
{}
{}
{}

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{blue!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{blue}} % Chapter number
{\color{blue}}
{\color{blue!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{3pt}\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\small} % Spacing and font options for subsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of tables
\titlecontents{table}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

%======================================================================================
%   MINI TABLE OF CONTENTS IN PART HEADS
%======================================================================================

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{lchapter}[0em] % Indenting
{\addvspace{15pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{blue}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{blue}} % Chapter number
{}
{\color{blue}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{lsection}[0em] % Indenting
{\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{}

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{lsubsection}[.5em] % Indentation
{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily} % Font settings
{}
{}
{}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@mypartnumtocformat}[2]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{blue!20}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\ecart}{\color{blue!70}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\centering#1}}\hskip\esp\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth-\ecart-\esp}{\Large\sffamily\centering#2}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% unnumbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@myparttocformat}[1]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\centering#1}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength\esp
\setlength\esp{4pt}
\newlength\ecart
\setlength\ecart{1.2cm-\esp}
\newcommand{\thepartimage}{}%
\newcommand{\partimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thepartimage}{#1}}%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
\else%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
\fi%
\startcontents%
\markboth{}{}%
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[blue!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north] at (4cm,-3.25cm){\color{blue!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\@Roman\c@part};
\node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
}};
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
\startcontents%
\phantomsection
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[blue!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\protect\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\protect\centering #1\quad\mbox{}}}}{#1}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HYPERLINKS IN THE DOCUMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=blue,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=blue,bold}%
\fi
}
}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

%========================================================================================
%   MAINMATTER
%========================================================================================

\mainmatter

\part{One}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}

\part{Two}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}

\end{document}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can use the `multicols` environment from `multicol` package inside the `\parbox`!

Comment: @touhami, thanks for your input.  Can you provide minimum code for your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. The `multicols` environment from [multicol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) package works fine inside `\parbox`.

The code

```
\node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}{
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
}};
```

To be replaced with

```
\node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){%
\parbox[t][][t]{\textwidth}{%
\columnsep=50pt
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
\end{multicols}}};
```

Note that we replace `\parbox[t][][t]{8.5cm}` with `\parbox[t][][t]{\textwidth}` and we adjusted `\columnsep=50pt`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating, ltablex, dcolumn}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}

%======================================================================================
%   MAIN TABLE OF CONTENTS
%======================================================================================

\usepackage{titletoc} % Required for manipulating the table of contents

\contentsmargin{0cm} % Removes the default margin

% Part text styling
\titlecontents{part}[0cm]
{\addvspace{20pt}\centering\large\bfseries}
{}
{}
{}

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{12pt}\large\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{blue!60}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{blue}} % Chapter number
{\color{blue}}
{\color{blue!60}\normalsize\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{section}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{3pt}\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{\hfill\color{black}\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{subsection}[1.25cm] % Indentation
{\addvspace{1pt}\small} % Spacing and font options for subsections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Subsection number
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number
[]

% List of figures
\titlecontents{figure}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

% List of tables
\titlecontents{table}[0em]
{\addvspace{-5pt}}
{\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1em}}
{}
{\ \titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage}
[]

%======================================================================================
%   MINI TABLE OF CONTENTS IN PART HEADS
%======================================================================================

% Chapter text styling
\titlecontents{lchapter}[0em] % Indenting
{\addvspace{15pt}\large\sffamily\bfseries} % Spacing and font options for chapters
{\color{blue}\contentslabel[\Large\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}\color{blue}} % Chapter number
{}
{\color{blue}\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries\;\titlerule*[.5pc]{.}\;\thecontentspage} % Page number

% Section text styling
\titlecontents{lsection}[0em] % Indenting
{\sffamily\small} % Spacing and font options for sections
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{1.25cm}} % Section number
{}
{}

% Subsection text styling
\titlecontents{lsubsection}[.5em] % Indentation
{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily} % Font settings
{}
{}
{}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm, bm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\@mypartnumtocformat}[2]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{blue!20}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\ecart}{\color{blue!70}\Large\sffamily\bfseries\centering#1}}\hskip\esp\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth-\ecart-\esp}{\Large\sffamily\centering#2}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% unnumbered part in the table of contents
\newcommand{\@myparttocformat}[1]{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\centering#1}}}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength\esp
\setlength\esp{4pt}
\newlength\ecart
\setlength\ecart{1.2cm-\esp}
\newcommand{\thepartimage}{}%
\newcommand{\partimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thepartimage}{#1}}%
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax%
\refstepcounter{part}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@mypartnumtocformat{\thepart}{#1}}{\partname~\thepart\ ---\ #1}}
\else%
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{\protect\@myparttocformat{#1}}{#1}}%
\fi%
\startcontents%
\markboth{}{}%
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[blue!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north] at (4cm,-3.25cm){\color{blue!40}\fontsize{220}{100}\sffamily\bfseries\@Roman\c@part};
\node[anchor=south east] at (\paperwidth-1cm,-\paperheight+1cm){%
\parbox[t][][t]{\textwidth}{%
\columnsep=50pt
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printcontents{l}{0}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}%
\end{multicols}}};
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#2}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@spart#1{%
\startcontents%
\phantomsection
{\thispagestyle{empty}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\node at (current page.north west){\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%   
\fill[blue!20](0cm,0cm) rectangle (\paperwidth,-\paperheight);
\node[anchor=north east] at (\paperwidth-1.5cm,-3.25cm){\parbox[t][][t]{15cm}{\strut\raggedleft\color{white}\fontsize{30}{30}\sffamily\bfseries#1}};
\end{tikzpicture}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\texorpdfstring{%
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
\noindent\protect\colorbox{blue!40}{\strut\protect\parbox[c][.7cm]{\linewidth}{\Large\sffamily\protect\centering #1\quad\mbox{}}}}{#1}}%
\@endpart}
\def\@endpart{\vfil\newpage
\if@twoside
\if@openright
\null
\thispagestyle{empty}%
\newpage
\fi
\fi
\if@tempswa
\twocolumn
\fi}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HYPERLINKS IN THE DOCUMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=blue,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{
open,
numbered,
addtohook={%
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=0 % chapter
\bookmarksetup{bold}%
\fi
\ifnum\bookmarkget{level}=-1 % part
\bookmarksetup{color=blue,bold}%
\fi
}
}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

%========================================================================================
%   MAINMATTER
%========================================================================================

\mainmatter

\part{One}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}

\part{Two}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}
\chapter{Question}
\section{Question}
\section{Answer}

\end{document}
```

[image]